# Django ORM SQL Raw Mysql

Tags: python, django, orm

select CONCAT(first_name,last_name)as broker_name,coupon_name,
(select count(user_details.id)from user_details join user on user.id=user_details.user_id and user.role_id=3 where referral_coupon_id=coupons.id) as tenat_referrals,
(select count(user_details.id) from user_details join user on user.id=user_details.user_id and user.role_id=2 where referral_coupon_id=coupons.id) as landloard_referrals
from user LEFT JOIN coupons on coupons.user_id=user.id where role_id=4

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

We want to help you. Could you please rephrase more clearly what is your problem so as we can help you ?

I hope your problem is already fixed nevertheless !

**I am sorry for my english level.**

Comment: I want to convert above query in Django ORM format